# Using Bumblebee with Wine Erro

Tags: wine, bumblebee

I've been trying to run a windows program with wine using optirun.

However when i do:

```
sudo optirun wine PROGRAM_NAME.exe
```

I get the following output:

```
wine:/home/USERNAME/.wine is not owned by you
```

Why won't it run?

Thank you.

Comment: Try it without `sudo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sudo` is causing it to run as `root`, not as `fawkes5`. Instead run `optirun wine PROGRAM_NAME.exe`. If you need `sudo` to run `optirun` then follow [this](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Install-and-usage) guide to give yourself permission to run it without sudo. Specifically you should run:

```
$ sudo groupadd bumblebee
$ sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee $USER
```

then log out and back in.

Answer (score -1):

If you still cant get it to run, I have run it fine using crossover. The free trial is available in Software Center or you can buy it from codeweavers.com
Please note: Bumblebee is NOT officially supported by codeweavers, but IT does run!